# Tensorflow transfer learning error - invalid literal for float(): 0&324597

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running a tensorflow transfer learning retrain session in Ubuntun 16.10 with the following code:

```html
python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
--how_many_training_steps 1000000 \
--model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
--output_graph=/tf_files/model_5/retrained_graph.pb \
--output_labels=/tf_files/model_5/retrained_labels.txt \
--image_dir /tf_files/images
```

The retraining session has encountered an error:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1012, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 816, in main
    bottleneck_tensor)
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 480, in get_random_cached_bottlenecks
    bottleneck_tensor)
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 405, in get_or_create_bottleneck
    bottleneck_values = [float(x) for x in bottleneck_string.split(',')]
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0&324597
```

Can't figure out why. Any pointers to solving this issues will be of great help!

Cheers,

Rahul

Comment: It's impossible to debug the issue without more details. How did you generate the various input files to the retrain script? Can you give a complete set of instructions to reproduce?